# UIPageViewController views messed up if user moves too quickly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIPageViewController` that uses an integer to tell which page it is on. It works fine, but if the user quickly swipes several times to get to a page further back, the integer changes more quickly than the views do, and then the whole thing falls apart (the app thinks it is on page 7 when it could be displaying page 3). What am I doing wrong? Is there a different method I should use to tell where I am? Thanks.

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if (pageNumber == 0) {
        pageNumber++;
        NSLog(@"%i", pageNumber);
        Two *two = [[Two alloc] init];
        return two;
    } else if (pageNumber == 1) {
        pageNumber++;
        NSLog(@"%i", pageNumber);
        Three *three = [[Three alloc] init];
        return three;
    } else if (pageNumber >= 2) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Presumably `pageNumber` is decremented in the corresponding `pageViewController:viewControllerBeforeViewController:`? When you say "the app thinks it is on page 7", do you mean that when you look at `pageNumber` after a set of very fast swipes, it's set to 7? Which view is displayed at that point?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If you swipe very quickly, the integer increases by a lot, but the pages do not turn as quickly, causing the integer and the actual page number to be out of sync, sometimes by a great amount.

Comment: But, since you're returning `nil` here whenever `pageNumber >= 2`, and not changing it, where else is `pageNumber` being incremented? What should be displayed? And what is actually displayed?

Comment: Sorry, that was an example. The app could be displaying page 2 when it thinks it is showing page 3.

Comment: By the way, this also happens if a user grabs the edge of the page and starts to move it, but then puts it and back stays on the current page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you're taking `pageNumber` for granted. `UIPageViewController` could only be asking for next `viewController` to preload it and you're already increasing `pageNumber`.

You were close when you noticed that "this also happens if a user grabs the edge of the page and starts to move it, but then puts it and back stays on the current page."

This method gets `UIViewController` for parameter and that is the only **real reference** you have.

Since you only have three pages one way to solve this would be:

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass: [One class]])
    {
        Two *two = [[Two alloc] init];
        return two;
    }
    else if ([viewController isKindOfClass: [Two class]])
    {
        Three *three = [[Three alloc] init];
        return three;
    }
    else
    {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Note: this code is not the best solution - i'm just trying to point out that you shouldn't be simply increasing/decreasing `pageNumber` in `viewControllerAfterViewController:`/`viewControllerBeforeViewController:`

You could also `[[... alloc ]init]` viewControllers before all this and reduce *initialization activity* of viewControllers in `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` methods to `loadView` (if it's not loaded) at most. For example (abbreviated):

```
    ...
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass: [One class]])
    {
        //Two *two = [[Two alloc] init]; //called before and two is someone's property
        if (![two isViewLoaded]) [two loadView];
        return two;
    }
    else if ...
```

For more pages you could also try tagging viewControllers (during their initialization). Since `UIViewController` itself doesn't have a tag property you could probably use `viewController.view.tag` or sublcass `UIViewController` and add it a `pageNumber` property (this would probably be close to THE solution.